# How obvious does an icon need to be for young readers to click to "read more"?

Tags: user-behavior, icons, menu

I have a photoblog that I am building, the prototype is on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/tfFCL). The focus in photos, but I also wanted to include a brief set of details. But I wanted this to be unobtrusive for power users that just want to browse pictures.

Are there any studies about what type of icons would be universally understood? For example "read more" becomes an eye sore to read on a photoblog. This is what I have so far

[image: screenshot]

So this audience is likely teen to early 20s who is more familiar with how to use technology.

But just in case, should I somehow draw more attention to the way to display text (do you even know what to do at this point?), and perhaps does placement affect how easy it is to interact with the article?

---

**EDIT**
Version 2

[image: version 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That icon is not a **read more** icon, it's more of a **drop down menu** or **bullet** / **unordered list** icon.

The best thing to do when showing and hiding content, would be to use textual links whose wording changes based on the toggle state.  You could still use an icon, but something that is known for toggling visible state.

Something like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLTGzn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdUN6s.png)</sup>

Comment: My mind read "unordered list" when I saw it. :)

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey - LoL ... yes, I thought it was a bullet list as well initially. Edited my answer to include those as well.

Comment: When I first added that icon, it was because I was going to use a list of things (location, skater, time, etc.). But I agree with the "more info"

Answer (score 2):

You could possible also use the (i) icon for information and simply have a close on the content you expose. This icon could float on top of the photos bottom-left if you wanted without much issue or put below the photo as you've done with more/less info.